# CakePHP 3.x Find records from current user only with paginate

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This seems like a thing that is probably super easy in CakePHP, but I cannot find a clear example.

I would think this works in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'where' => ['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')],
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ];
    $slates = $this->paginate($this->Slates);

    $this->set(compact('slates'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['slates']);
}
```

But I always get the full collection back. I am most definitely logged in, I have two unique users, I have created records with each of them.

Comment: shouldnt `where` be `conditions`

Comment: @yBrodsky is that really it? I will check.

Comment: @yBrodsky please put that as an answer, you are 100% correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change where to conditions. Couldnt find a reference in the docs.

```
$this->paginate = [
        'conditions' => ['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')],
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ];
```

Comment: The values in the paginate array are simply passed to a find call, so the keys you can use here are the same as you'd use there.